# How can I keep background music playing when switching ViewControllers?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I currently have a SettingsViewController which handles starting/stopping music and adjusting the musics volume.

Is it possible to make the music stay on after unwinding the SettingsViewController? And after turning on the music and switching ViewControllers, can I re-open the SettingsViewController and turn off the music as well? Please let me know the limitations.

Here is the code for my SettingsViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>

@interface SettingsViewController : UIViewController <AVAudioPlayerDelegate>
{
    AVAudioPlayer *audioPlayer;
    IBOutlet UISwitch *Switch;
    IBOutlet UISlider *Slider;

}
-(IBAction)Switch:(UISwitch *)sender;
-(IBAction)Slider:(UISlider *)sender;
@end
```

And here is the code for my SettingsViewController.m

```
#import "SettingsViewController.h"

@interface SettingsViewController ()

@end

@implementation SettingsViewController

-(IBAction)Switch:(UISwitch *)sender{
    NSUserDefaults *standardDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

    if(sender.tag == 0){
        if(sender.on){
            [standardDefaults setObject:@"On" forKey:@"keyName"];
            //choosing and setting the music file
            NSString *music = [[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"bgmusic1" ofType:@"mp3"];
            audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:music] error:NULL];
            audioPlayer.delegate = self;
            audioPlayer.numberOfLoops= -1; //sets the music to loop infinitely
            [audioPlayer play]; //plays the music


        } else if (sender.on == 0){
            [standardDefaults setObject:@"Off" forKey:@"keyName"];
            [audioPlayer stop]; //stops the music
        }
    }
    [standardDefaults synchronize];

}

-(IBAction)Slider:(UISlider *)sender{
    audioPlayer.volume = sender.value / 100.0; //will adjust the volume of the music according the slider value
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

Let me know what needs to be modified!

Comment: You should move play music code in AppDelegate

Comment: That's what I was doing initially @MikeAlter however I was having a harder time figuring out how to control the music in a ViewController from AppDelegate... If there is a simple way to explain how to properly do it, please let me know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do that in your AppDelegate.

To access it from anywhere, import it's .h file in your ViewControllers .m file and access it with

```
MyAppDelegate *appDelegate = (MyAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
```

Make the audioplayer to a property in your AppDelegate.h to allow public access (for e.g. your other viewControllers)

```
@interface AppDelegate: NSAppDelegate
 {
    IBOutlet UISwitch *Switch;
    IBOutlet UISlider *Slider; 
}

@property AVAudioPlayer *audioPlayer; // <------
-(IBAction)Switch:(UISwitch *)sender;
-(IBAction)Slider:(UISlider *)sender;
@end
```

Then adjust each call of your audioplayer in the m file to adopt the change in your h file.

```
//Instead of [audioplayer doSomething] write...
[self.audioplayer doSomething];

// in modern objective-c you can use also
[_audioplayer doSomething];
```

To call your audioplayer from other ViewControllers then implement the first mentioned code and call your player like so

```
[appDelegate.audioplayer doSomething]
```

Comment: Sorry could you elaborate? I'm able to change my code to make the AppDelegate hold the music but how would I start/stop/change volume of the music from a different ViewController?

Comment: Updated answer!

Comment: Thank you! I managed to get it working following this. AppDelegate has always been so tricky for me... One last question, it might be a bit unrelated but, do you know how I might be able to keep the slider and switch the same after leaving/coming back to the SettingsViewController?

Comment: You need to save the values in a variable and load it's value in the viewControllers - (void)viewWillAppear method. If your viewController get's deallocated (kicked out of memory) you need to either use a strong reference to keep it alive or save it in a separate data model. If you need it more detailed ask a new question and post the link here.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43490047/uiswitch-uislider-values-when-switching-viewcontrollers here ya go

Answer (score 0):

Because your `audioPlayer` will be release when its parent `SettingsViewController` released.

So you should add it to global and you can make it with Singleton Pattern.

Create `BackgroundPlayer.h`

```
@interface BackgroundPlayer: NSObject {
   AVAudioPlayer *audioPlayer;
}

+ (id)sharedManager;

@end
```

and `BackgroundPlayer.m`

```
@implementation BackgroundPlayer

static BackgroundPlayer* sharedInstance = nil;

+ (BackgroundPlayer*) sharedInstance {
    if (sharedInstance == nil) {
        sharedInstance = [[super allocWithZone:NULL] init];
    }

    return sharedInstance;
}

- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];

    return self;
}

-(void)playAudio:(NSString *) audioPath
{
    audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:audioPath] error:NULL];
    audioPlayer.delegate = self;
    audioPlayer.numberOfLoops= -1; //sets the music to loop infinitely
    [audioPlayer play]; //plays the music
}

-(void)setVolum:(float) volum {
    if (audioPlayer) {
        audioPlayer.volume = sender.value / 100.0;
    }
}
```

Then you just call

```
NSString *music = [[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"bgmusic1" ofType:@"mp3"];
[[BackgroundPlayersharedInstance] playAudio:music];
```

Comment: So I call the last part into SettingsViewController.h? And that would also mean importing BackgroundPlayer.h into SettingsViewController, right?

Comment: I haven't tested this yet but will this also keep the volume of the music persistent to what the slider value is?

Comment: Sure. Just call `[[BackgroundPlayersharedInstance] setVolum:sender.value / 100.0];`

Comment: Sorry I wasn't able to get it working with the code provided... Is there more to this?

Comment: No, that's it. What issue did you meet?

Comment: A few, I will list them here... (In BackgroundPlayer.m: playAudio error - expected identifier, setVolum error - use of undeclared identifier 'sender') and (in SettingsViewController.m: [[BackgroundPlayersharedInstance] playAudio:music]; error - use of undeclared identfier)

Comment: Also + (id)sharedManager; isn't used/created - what is it's purpose?

Comment: I was still not able to get your code working even after your edit. I would still like to know how to play the music using your approach, if there are still changes that can be made

Comment: Hi, My approach is use Singleton Pattern. You can take a look on here. [Singleton Pattern](http://www.galloway.me.uk/tutorials/singleton-classes/)